# Why doesn't Applicative instance for Data.Vector diagonalize its result?

Tags: haskell

So I wanted to `fmap` a function over several `Vector`s of equal size. Well, `Applicative` to the rescue!

```
λ➔ let f x y z = x * y + z
λ➔
λ➔ let va = V.fromList [10, 20, 30]
λ➔ let vb = V.fromList [2, 5, 3]
λ➔ let vc = V.fromList [1, 2, 3]
λ➔
λ➔ f <$> va <*> vb <*> vc
fromList [21,22,23,51,52,53,31,32,33,41,42,43,101,102,103,61,62,63,61,62,63,151,152,153,91,92,93]
```

... whoops. Far from what was expected.

---

From [the source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.10.12.3/docs/src/Data-Vector.html) it's clear that the Applicative instance is defined in terms of Monad's; `(<*>) = ap`; `(>>=) = flip concatMap`. Which explains why my expression blows up:

```
λ➔ (+) <$> V.fromList [10, 20, 30] <*> V.fromList [1, 2, 3]
fromList [11,12,13,21,22,23,31,32,33]
```

It just enumerates all argument combinations. This looks like a really poor definition for `(<*>)`, since the result blows up combinatorially.

Rather, it could've *diagonalize* the result to produce `[11, 22, 33]`, something like this:

```
instance Applicative Vector where
    pure = repeat
    fs <*> xs = zipWith ($) fs xs
```

This still makes a valid `Applicative` instance. And it's way more useful, in my view.

Are there reasons for the instance being written the way it is, besides plain oversight?

Also, seasoned advice on further action is appreciated.

---

<sup>*edit: corrected earlier `pure = single`</sup>

Comment: That's not a legal Applicative instance. `\x -> pure id <*> x` is not the same as `id`. Look at the Applicative instance for `ZipList` for a related example.

Comment: @Carl sorry for earlier harsh comment; looks like `pure` should be `repeat` of some sort...

Comment: I was wondering too - most likely I miss something right now but this one (`\x -> pure id <*> x == id`) seems to hold with `pure = repeat`

Comment: I second @Carl, but it's worth pointing out that it's possible to write a correct `pure` operation for the  `Stream` type from [`Data.Vector.Fusion.Stream`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.10.12.3/docs/Data-Vector-Fusion-Stream.html). I'd just use `Vector.zipWith`, though.

Comment: I was being so bold because this instance was absolutely implementable in Idris... I did it and it worked.

Comment: @ulidtko implemented like a *verified* applicative (https://github.com/reynir/Verified) ?

Comment: @LuisCasillas, yes, the underlying `Stream` type allows a `repeat`, and this instance consequently. The current instance just looks way beyond any measure of usefullness.

Comment: @ulidtko: Does the vector type that you're using in Idris encode the size of the vector into the type itself?  Basically, the problem is that for a correct implementation, (a) all the vectors need to be the same length, and (b) `pure` needs to know what that length is.  So if you have a dependently typed sized vector type, that does support a zippy `Applicative` instance.

Comment: @LuisCasillas you are correct. But (a) can be overcomed with a weak (min-length) zip semantics, (b) with infinite lazy pure. Right?

Comment: @uidtko: But every Haskell `Vector` must have a finite length, so infinite lazy `pure` is not possible.

Comment: @LuisCasillas the underlying implementation uses a `Stream` data type which is capable of supporting the zippy instance. It doesn't need to expose infinite vectors at the library API.

Comment: I find the value judgments and the criticism of the library authors in this question and your follow-on comments distasteful. Please don't do that; stick to technical, objective questions instead. A cooperative atmosphere is more conducive to solving problems than the antagonistic one that this kind of behavior can easily set up.

Comment: @ulidtko: No, that's not how `vector` works.  `Stream` and `Vector` are not isomorphic types; the former can represent infinite sequences, but the latter cannot.  `Stream` is a stream of elements, `Vector` is a finite in-memory array. The "underlying" aspect of it is that a large number of `Vector` operations are implemented as `op = Vector.unstream . Stream.op . Vector.stream`; the library has rules to eliminate intermediate `Vector.unstream` and `Vector.stream` chains to reduce memory use.

Comment: @DanielWagner please forgive me the moot tone; I did inspect the source before asking and was trying to double-check before starting a proposal/pull-request. Finding 4⁵ records in my vector instead of just 4 was... surprising and interesting. Also I didn't note the important difference with Idris' type system and thought an equivalent was possible in Haskell too.

Comment: @CarstenKönig https://github.com/reynir/Verified/pull/4 `:)`

Answer (score 11):

It is not merely oversight. For the `Applicative` instance to be correct, we would need an implementation of `pure` that behaved like an infinitely long vector, all with the same element. (And because the API provides scans, the library would then also need to be able to have values that behaved like arbitrary infinitely long vectors.) The current implementation uses arrays for performance reasons; and one cannot have an infinitely sized array for obvious reasons.

You can achieve what you want in the way we used to do before the zippy applicatives became popular. There are functions specialized to the number of arguments you want to zip together, with the usual [`zipWithN`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.10.12.3/docs/Data-Vector.html#g:23) names.

Comment: Thank you. Again, my apologies for harsh asking tone.

Comment: @ulidtko I've said worse myself; and I hope when I do it again in the future you police me back. =)

Answer (score 5):

I would just use `Vector.zipWith`.

One thing I've learned from using `Vector` is that you generally want to stick to the library's operations and steer away from the `Functor`/`Applicative`/`Monad` instances.  Why?  Because several of the library's types can't support the type classes.  For example, if you write a bunch of code using `Data.Vector.Vector`'s `Functor` instance, and later decide to use `Data.Vector.Unboxed.Vector`, you're going to have to change all your `fmap`s to `Data.Vector.Unboxed.map`, because unboxed vectors are not `Functor` instances—the element type carries an `Unbox` constraint.

It's unfortunate, but it's just an example of a long-unsolved Haskell problem (can't make instance of `* -> *` class when the type requires a constraint on the type parameter).

Comment: That is indeed a “long-unsolved” problem, but is actually solved for quite some time now: constraint kinds allow instances of `* -> *` with constraints on the parameter. Of course, the standard functor classes aren't going to get constrained any time soon, and no library that offers the generalisations seems to have taken off yet. I'll keep advertising [my implementation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories)...

Answer (score 0):

You can make a type:

data DiagonalisingVector a = DiagVector (Either a (Vector a))

It's easy to write the applicative instance for this that forwards everything for Right, and applies left with each element of a Right or with another singular Left. Left represents pure values which can be considered to occupy all points.

This will do what you want quite easily and you can begin to tailor and optimise it as you please.

Comment: However, maybe you shouldn't be using applicative and use a function or operator that promises to do exactly what you want regardless of the type and which is undefined for types for which it cannot be done.